# How can I see the execution time, after run Word Count in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, time, execution

How can I see the execution time, after run **Word Count** in Hadoop ?

I'd like to see the time, that the jobs are complete.

Comment: check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365812/how-to-find-the-cpu-time-taken-by-a-map-reduce-task-in-hadoop

Comment: If you want to see the time and the details of every single job on Hadoop, you will have to go to the Jobbrowser or JobHistory.

Comment: How can I go to Jobbrowser or JobHistory ?